# PHP to javascript JSON.Parse twice

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest

I have this in PHP

```
$invalid_code_msg = ['error' => 'Invalid purchase code. Please double check your purchase code and try again!'];
throw new Exception(json_encode($invalid_code_msg));
```

In js:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    console.error(xhr.statusText);

};
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (this.readyState === 4){

        if (this.status === 200) { 

            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(data, data.error)

            //here data is still a string unless I parse it twice?
        }
    }

};


xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("pc=" + purchase_code.value);
```

I am trying to figure out why data is still a string unless I parse it twice?

```
data is still a string after first JSON.parse 

{"error":"Invalid purchase code. Please double check your purchase code and try again!"}
```

Comment: Can you do a console.log before you parse it the first time? Like `console.log(xhr.responseText)`. Also, how is that exception handled? Just throwing an exception would either show a full error (not only your json encoded message) which wouldn't be valid JSON if it was displayed directly (having display_errors on), or it wouldn't show anything at all. Do you have some custom error handler/doing some `try/catch` or similar that encodes the message again before returning a response?

Comment: Check the exception handler on the PHP side? It may be calling json_encode again when creating the response.